# Angular 6 alterante way to global css

Tags: css, angular, sass, handsontable

I'm using Handsontable in one of my component, and it forces me to include it's css globally in my angular.json file

```
"styles": [
         "./src/styles.scss",
          "./node_modules/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css"
       ],
```

and it affects my calendar component all over my application.
How can i include this css only for that handsontable component and disable it for all other components.

writing import in handsontable component scss file doesn't work.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why it should affect calendar component? If you are reusing `handsontable` styles in your calendar, may be it is easier to override them in `callendar`'s styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as below. Pay attention to `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`. This will disable default `Emulated DOM`, so that styles of this component, will be applicable to children as well. Other wise, by default `Emulate DOM`, protects scopes of each component (that is why it was not working in your case).

Refer to [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) also.

However, that won't fix your problem actually. Because, as per documentation:

> [ViewEncapsulation] None means that Angular does no view encapsulation. Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the HTML.

What effectively means, that the output will be in global scope any way.

So probably it is easier just add once in your main `styles.scss`:

```
@import '~/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css';
```

Working with `ViewEncapsulation.None` encapsulation.

```
// component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  template: `<hot-table ....></hot-table>`,
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class TableComponent {
...
}

// component.scss
@import '~/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-home-component',
    template: '<div></div>',
    styleUrls: [
        'path/handsontable.full.css',
        './home.component.css'
    ], 
})
export class HomeComponent{}
```

Comment: This is not gonna work. Because of `ViewEncapsulation` and also path specified incorrectly, `node_modules` some few levels up the directory structure, it should be something like: `../../node_modules....` depending on how many levels deep component is.

Comment: @muradm Question wants to apply css to only specific component, not whole application

Comment: Yes, but that component is also Angular component, and you can't style parent or child components from current component because of Emulated DOM. That is the problem of the question: `writing import in handsontable component scss file doesn't work`